# Troubleshooting a Motherboard / Monitor combination

Tags: motherboard, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

I have a brand new [H97M-ITX/ac](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157526) motherboard and a [27” QNIX Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OCTOJVG) and they don’t seem to work together.

- I’ve plugged the motherboard into another monitor using both VGA and DVI-D and it works.
- I’ve plugged the monitor into another computer using DVI-D and it works.
- I’ve used the same DVI-D cable that worked with the motherboard & monitor.

Motherboard is out of the case, it has RAM and CPU and CPU Cooler. When I remove all the RAM, it gives a POST code. When I put it back it starts up fine with no complaining.

When I plug the monitor into the motherboard and turn the motherboard on, the motherboard powers up, the monitor turns grey with a blue LED but it never shows the BIOS screen.

**Edit**: While I'm not certain it's a resolution issue, that makes the most sense.  A HDMI -> DVI-D cable didn't work, three different DVI-D cables didn't work, the motherboard worked fine on another, very similar monitor (but not the exact same model).  I was able to swap the two monitors we have and both computers (new and old) are happy with the exchanged monitors, so that's the plan now. Awarding the bounty to the first person who hunted down the resolution issue.

Comment: You could try removing the power cable from the PSU then remove the CMOS battery for about 15 minutes. Put the battery back in then plug the PSU power cable back in. See if it boots/displays.

Comment: Do you have access to the monitor OSD when it is connected to the motherboard and both things are powered up? Here is [how it should look like](http://www.anandtech.com/Gallery/Album/3541).

Comment: Tom, let us know if you have any luck with a BIOS update if you try that. Though as I mentioned in my answer, it seems like it is a resolution issue, which wouldn't likely be resolved by a BIOS update. Anyway the video card solution I suggested should work.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- Make sure that you connect devices to one power cord. Try to rotate one of power plugs 180 degrees (exchange Live and Neutral). There might be some current going through signal cable.
- How long is the DVI-D cable? Try to change the cable, as it can have weak quality.
- Have you tried to run Windows and then to connect the LCD monitor?
- Check if your set can work with HDMI - DVI-D cable.
- Does the monitor display any OSD? Can you check if information of the signal is available?

Answer (score 1):

You could install a video card and run the monitor off of that instead. This may be your best bet.

It may be a resolution issue. The 27” QNIX Monitor description through your link states that the PC graphic card should surport QHD(2560x1440). And the on-board graphics of your motherboard (again information available through your link) seem to max out at 1920x1200. The specs on the monitor at newegg state "Your video card has to support at least 2560 resolution with Dual link DVI."

The  GTX750 NVidia card  is reported to work and I believe is compatible with your motherboard, but you'll want to make sure.

You might also try updating the BIOS and/or changing the video settings within the BIOS. Read your montherboard manual on resetting the BIOS, just in case. But from the above, this seems unlikely, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different DVI-D cable.

I had the same problem with a known good HDMI cable. It just didn't like being hooked up to a certain computer and a certain monitor. Worked with everything else though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem seems to be the following:

- From the monitor specs: 27inch SAMSUNG PLS Glossy `2560x1440` High Resolution WQHD Panel;
- From the motherboard specs: Supports `DVI-D` with max. resolution up to `1920x1200 @ 60Hz`;

It seems that the integrated graphics card can't negotiate appropriate resolution with the monitor. [Here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/30360?start=0&tstart=0) is some info that could be helpful or at least help you with the search.
If you have an older/not high-resolution monitor/TV(1080P) you can test with it. It should work.